# Weird character "Â" before degrees Celcius symbol "°C"

Tags: c#, unicode

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396367/how-do-i-find-out-if-my-string-contains-the-micro-unicode-character) a day ago regarding Greek Unicode characters, and now I have a question which builds upon that one.

After extracting all my data, I have attempted to prepare it for import into Excel.  I had to chose a tab delimited file because some of my data contains commas (lucky me!).

The issue I'm running into is a very weird character after I import the data into Excel.

The column data in Notepad++ looks like this:

```
Total Suspended Solids @105°C
```

The Excel cell data looks like this:

```
Total Suspended Solids @105Â°C
```

I don't understand why this is happening.  Does this have something to do with how the degrees symbol is represented?

p.s. I the symbols in this question are direct copy and paste

Comment: Explicitly setting the output stream format to UTF8 will correct the issue in Excel.
var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8)

Answer (score 11):

1. (More likely) Excel is interpreting your textual data as latin-1 or windows-1252, and not UTF-8. "Â°" is what you get if you take the UTF-8 bytes for "°" (`0xc2 0xb0`) and interpret each byte as a character of latin-1 or windows-1252. Is there an option for input encoding when you do your import?
2. (Less likely) Excel is doing the right thing, but you're double-encoding your data (encoding as UTF-8, then re-interpreting it as an 8-bit encoding and encoding *again* as UTF-8 or any other Unicode encoding). Notepad++ evidence is against this one.

Comment: @Hobbis: OK, however, the original is in Excel, and this special "Â" character is not present

Comment: Round-tripping the data could introduce the extra character if you are converting the code page from not-UTF8 to UTF8.

Comment: The degree character is 0xB0 in Windows-1252, IBM-437, and ISO Latin 1.  When this is encoded into UTF-8, the 0xB0 becomes 0xC2 0xB0.  It looks like Excel is reading this as "ANSI" by default.  When you import the data, you can tell it to use UTF-8 explicitly by selecting the "File Origin" - at least that is what it was in Excel 2003.

Comment: Or, as Philippe Leybaert points out, you could just write the file with a Windows-1252 encoding instead of UTF-8, as long as you're not trying to use any characters that are unavailable in that encoding.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not absolutely sure, but I think Excel expects Windows-1252 character encoding, so make sure you create your text file using **`Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")`**.

For example:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName,false,Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"))
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTF-8 BOM for your file.