# SignalR encoding in JSON

Tags: c#, json, encoding, signalr

I have a Windows service that publishes data to a .NET client and a web client over SignalR. I've recently had some funny issues, but can't quite get a consistent behavior.

The problem lies in serializing the degrees sign, i.e. "°C". Most of the time it is serialized correctly, but I've had a few times where I see the following in my debugger:

[image: Wrong encoding]

See how the first time the "°" is serialized correctly, but the second time we see the question marks in the diamonds?

I've read this means it is an invalid UTF-8 character. But then why do all the other properties serialize correctly? This is a screenshot where you see one correct and one incorrect, but the entire JSON contains hundreds of these "°C" strings that look correct.

So why this one exception? It's not always the same position/property, and it doesn't always happen. This makes me think it must be a combination with preceding/succeeding characters, no?

Any ideas how to fix this or at least how to investigate this further?

**Update**

This is how I do serialization. I set it up on startup:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StructuredAmountJsonConverter());
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(_lifetimeScope);

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

What's happening here is I'm telling SignalR to use Autofac to resolve dependencies. Then I register my JSON.NET serializer. The JSON.NET serializer has one custom converter, which converts my Amount class to the structure you see above (with a value and a unit property).

So you could think the problem lies in the converter, but then why is it working 95% of the time? Or should I specify the encoding in my converter?

**Update 2**

I've been using Fiddler to capture my network traffic and I can't see the wrong characters there. So I'm guessing the encoding problem is at the client side. I will investigate further.

**Update 3**

I've managed to capture the traffic in Fiddler and while it looks good in the Text view, when I select the HexView I do see something weird:

[image: HexView]

Notice how it says "Â°C" instead of "°C". So maybe it is sending it from the server in the wrong way?

Also, keep in mind my client is a .NET (WPF) client. This is my code to connect on the client side (simplified):

```
var url = "myUrl...";
_hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);

var hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
hubProxy.On<object>("receive", OnDataReceived);

await _hubConnection.Start();
```

And when receiving data:

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataContract>(obj.ToString(), new StructuredAmountJsonConverter());
```

**Update 4**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406707/weird-character-%C3%82-before-degrees-celcius-symbol-c) makes me think this is happening:

- The server/SignalR is sending my data as UTF-8, but the client is expecting latin-1 or Windows-1252 (probably the latter). So now I need to find out how I can make it use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

May I know how you are serializing the objects? I think there is a way to specify the encoding types for serializing special characters like this. Here is a link I found- [Special characters in object making JSON invalid (DataContractJsonSerializer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412442/special-characters-in-object-making-json-invalid-datacontractjsonserializer)

Comment: @Peter I have tried replicating this using Newtonsoft.Json using a dummy List of 100 records containg °C in the similar format of your Json, it worked fine.

Comment: Hm, that's what makes it so weird. It shouldn't happen... Any ideas on how I can capture the raw bytes? Or see what encoding is being used?

Comment: At the client I think you might have to set the encoding type and content type. Something like this- "application/json; charset=UTF-8". This setting can be done in the headers or if your are using jQuery it's much easier. Can you show how you are consuming the JSON at client side?